# Least significant bit for a number in R?

Tags: r

This may have been answered in other languages, but I am having trouble googling the answer, probably because the language is named R, but I need a piece of code in R that accepts a number and returns the least significant bit.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [bitwise operations](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/bitwise.html) for this:

```
bitwAnd(n, 1)
```

However, beware that this is coercing your input vector to integer, and it only works up to 2<sup>31</sup>−1.

Answer (score 2):

You may also use `intToBits()` which returns a 32 raw (byte) vector with each bit separately.

```
> intToBits(7)[1] # access 1st bit
[1] 01
```

Anyway, the solution with `bitwAnd()` will be faster for accessing single bits.